# Why my android application's all static variables are destroyed when the app is in background for a long period of time?

Tags: android, variables, static, background, scope

If I leave my the application in background for about 12 hours, all the static variables are erased and the application goes nuts.

Why does this happen ?

What is the correct way to keep application level (scope) variables that are never destroyed until the application terminates ?

Thanks in advance,
Afzal

Answer (score 1):

You application probably get destroyed by the system you should keep state of your application using `onSaveInstanceState`  `onRestoreInstanceState` mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Your application obviously gets destroyed. You should consider the situation as relaunched.

Comment: But it resumes from the same activity that was last displayed. It does not starts the main activity. And it does some work while in the background (an HTTP call every 20 mins) so this means that it also stops doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think 12 hours is too big a time for Android to keep your app in memory. In this time, probably your app, looks like is destroyed by Android.

So, best bet is to try to save your state / data to database onDestroy() of the activity. Look at Android's [Component Cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles).